# Method createjs.Stage return an error with easeljs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs

When i get the canvas, and send for create the stage i get this string error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of undefined.
```

My init function:

```
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    screen_width = canvas.width;
    screen_height = canvas.height;

    contentManager = new ContentManager();
    contentManager.SetDownloadCompleted(startGame);
    contentManager.StartDownload();
}
```

The block of code that gives error is:

```
p.enableDOMEvents = function(enable) {
    if (enable == null) { enable = true; }
    var n, o, ls = this._eventListeners;
    if (!enable && ls) {
        for (n in ls) {
            o = ls[n];
            o.t.removeEventListener(n, o.f);
        }
        this._eventListeners = null;
    } else if (enable && !ls) {
        var t = window.addEventListener ? window : document;
        var _this = this;
        ls = this._eventListeners = {};
        ls["mouseup"] = {t:t, f:function(e) { _this._handleMouseUp(e)} };
        ls["mousemove"] = {t:t, f:function(e) { _this._handleMouseMove(e)} };
        ls["dblclick"] = {t:t, f:function(e) { _this._handleDoubleClick(e)} };
        t = this.canvas;
        if (t) { ls["mousedown"] = {t:t, f:function(e) { _this._handleMouseDown(e)} }; }

        for (n in ls) {
            o = ls[n];
            o.t.addEventListener(n, o.f);
        }
    }
```

especially this block:

```
    for (n in ls) {
        o = ls[n];
        o.t.addEventListener(n, o.f);
    }
```

When the value of 'n' is `BitmapAnimation_initialize`, gives error. I found this code into Stage.js, the file accompanies the rar of easeljs v0.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this error if you comment out the contentManager code? Seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
```

Do you actually have a DOM element with id "testCanvas"?

I got this error when building my first EaselJS app, because I had a typo in id...

Answer (score 0):

You may have added something to the prototype of `object` (So did I). The javascript for-each loop doesn't distinguish between "real" and prototype-properties.

@developers of this library: as recommended by Douglas Crockford (see [link](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)), the loop should check its properties first:

```
for (n in ls) {
  if (ls.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
    o = ls[n];
    o.t.addEventListener(n, o.f);
  } 
}
```